# Error 500 when trying to hide server information from response

Tags: .net, iis, webforms

I have a webforms application in .Net Framwork 4.5 and I'm trying to hide server information from the response headers. I already have the following configuration on web.config:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        ...
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

It works fine, but if I add `<requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">` I get error 500 when entering the web site. It works fine in dev environment but it breaks in production. Any ideia why?
Thanks

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I found out that  the production environment uses an older IIS version that does not support that setting. I had to use another config to get the same result.

Comment: Because requestFiltering was introduced in IIS7, there will be problems if this property is used in IIS6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/